# Kafka Producer to distribute messages to all partitions equally

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have a producer that send messages to kafka topic. My topic has 10 partitions in same consumer group and I am looking for round robin distribution of messages. I have specified RoundRobinPartitioner in producer config and even tried setting batch.size to 0 assuming that will not batch any messages and will do round robin. However, I always see only 5 partitions get messages all the time. I am not specifying any key while sending message to topic. Any idea what am I missing to get the desired behavior. I am okay to enable batching as long as these batches are distributed to all partitions. Any help here would be highly appreciated.

Producer config below.

RoundRobinPartition

EnableIdempotence,true

BatchSize, 0

no explict Key added

I have produced a few thousands of messages and couldn't really observe the distribution. Can I achieve round robin with a few thousands of messages..?

I am using kafka-clients:3.1.2.

Comment: There was bug in earlier Kafka Client versions which excatly had the problem you describe. Maybe add some more information, e.g. which Kafka version you are using.

Comment: I am using kafka-clients:3.1.2. Do you know a version that fixed this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't set the partitioner to the old RoundRobinPartitioner as setting it manually produces the problem you described. See also this question: [Kafka RoundRobin partitioner not distributing messages to all the partitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65363484/kafka-roundrobin-partitioner-not-distributing-messages-to-all-the-partitions).

As in earlier Kafka client versions there was a bug which leads to uneven distribution of UniformStickyPartitioner which got the new default partitioner you should upgrade the depedency to version 3.3.0 or newer. See the following bug report for further information: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-10888

Try to use kafka client version 3.3.0 or newer.

Comment: thank you Tobias for the suggestion. I have upgraded to 3.4.0 and can see the default partitioner is taking care of message distribution across partitions. Greatly appreciated.